# Tags: American or British spelling

Tags: tags, tag-synonyms, discussion

What should be the standard spelling for tags where the American and British spellings differ?

For instance: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronisation

I expect "synchronization" to appear any time.

Obviously synonyms can take care of the fragmentation, but one has to "win". It seems to me that mixing the two will be too dissonant.

(I also see that "sync" is out there too. That will need to be synonymized.)

Comment: perhaps you can discuss this in meta.stackoverflow.com, because this issue is a global one, not only related to Android

Comment: Apparently it has: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us . I've updated my original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this discussion on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us): tags should be standardized on American spelling. Content of posts should *not* be changed; leave it as the author wrote it.

Comment: Agreed, the American spelling should be the way to go

Comment: Ungrateful colonists, abandoning your mother-land and mother-tongue! ;)

Comment: I'm with Al on this.

Comment: So... non-Americans simply does not exist in this website? I personally don't mind using either American or British spellings (I freely mixes them, as a native speaker of neither), but your rationale for preferring American spelling seems a bit off to me.

Comment: No, that is not what I am implying at all. I am merely trying to determine which spelling for **tags** should be used when there is a conflict. I expect that there will be synonyms created for alternate spellings. Besides, it's not up to me; the decision has already been made at the network level.

Comment: Ahem... for my first non-serious comment on this site, I'd like to concur with GAThrawn and say: "Bwa ha ha ha ha !" :-D